# How to make distinction between two select dropdowns with same ngModel?

Tags: angular

I have a parent compo where i am using child - compo ( filter ) which has select dropdown with ngModel.
I need to call my child component twice in the parent,but the problem is that when i select something from the dropdown it reflects automatic and on the other select loaded from the second calling of the child compo.I want when i select the first dropdown from the first call of my child compo,to not be reflected on the second.

```
// parent compo

  <app-filter [sportLeagues]="sportLeagues" [teams]="teams"></app-filter>
  <app-filter [sportLeagues]="sportLeagues" [teams]="teams"></app-filter>

// child compo

  <div class="league-filter">
        <div>
            <div class="label__parent">
                <label>League filter</label>
            </div>
            <div class="league-filter-dropdown">
                <select [ngModel]="league_id" name="league_id" id="league_id"
                    (ngModelChange)="selectedLeagueFilterHandler($event)">
                    <option *ngFor="let sportLeague of sportLeagues; index as i;" [ngValue]="sportLeague.id">
                        {{ sportLeague.name }}
                    </option>
                </select>
                <button class="clear-filter-btn" *ngIf="league_id"
                    (click)="selectedLeagueFilterHandler(null)">
                    Clear filter
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is your app-filter counts dynamic or only two ones ?

Comment: Make list model and in ngFor assing each of them dynamically fro app-filter

Answer (score 0):

in js values are by reference. so sportLeagues for both components are actually the same variable. if you want to distinguish this components reference inputs you should have setter and getter for inputs and make a copy of the input. then you can emit the selected value.

```
@Output selectedFilter = new EventEmitter();
_sportLeagues;
@Input set sportLeagues(val) {
    this._sportLeagues = [...val];
}
get sportLeagues() {
    return this._sportLeagues;
}
```

now you just need to emit the selected filter to the parent;

```
selectedLeagueFilterHandler() {
    this.selectedFilter.emit(this.sportLeagues);
}
```

and handle it in parent component:

```
<app-filter (selectedFilter)="filterSelected($event)" [sportLeagues]="sportLeagues" [teams]="teams"></app-filter>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But i don't need to emit value from child to parent.I need to have two dynamic ngModels on both select dropdown's,i think the same ngModel name is making problem here or not ? :S

Comment: I can't.They need to have same names because of the methods that are using this models but difference referenced.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is that you pass as `@Input` to your "childs-compo" the same object or array. So a change in the object make the "change is proppagated". I suggest make a copy of the data in the setters. It's difficult without know about your code. If I imagine sportLeagues is an array of objects, you can has in the child-component

```
_sportLeagues:any[] //<--declare a new variable
@Input set sportLeagues(value)
{
  this._sportLeagues=value.map(x=>{...x}) //<--in a setter make a copy
}
```

So, if anywhere of your code you has

```
this._sportLeagues=newValue //<--this change the inner array
```